# jQuery form validation fails only on a specific input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a fairly straightforward validation function that only checks if input is empty or not. I'm using it across a half dozen different forms and it seems to be working everywhere except one specific input `id="driver_first_name"` . Can't figure out why it fails there.

If I leave all fields empty I get errors on all of them, and is generally correct across any combination I have tried except `driver_first_name` In the case that I fill out everything except `driver_first_name` the form submits anyways.

Any insight on what might be going on here?

Thank you!

My Validation function is this:

```
    function validateForm(form, fields) { //add exit anbimation and reset the container state
    $(".form-input-error").remove();
    var result=false;
    $.each( fields.rules, function( key, value ) {
        if(!$("#"+key+"").val()){
            $("#"+key+"").addClass("form-error");
            $( "<div class='form-input-error'>"+value.message+"</div>" ).insertBefore("#"+key+"");
             result = false;
            //console.log(this.val());
        }
        else{
            $("#"+key+"").removeClass("form-error");
             result = true;
        }   
});
     return result;
}
```

I am calling my validation on my submit triggers, generally like this for fields that should not be empty:

```
$(".app-canvas").on('click', ".submitNewDriver", function () {//list all drivers trigger
            var checkInputs = {
        rules: {
            driver_first_name: {
                message: "First Name is Required"
            },
            driver_last_name: {
                message: "Last Name is Required"
            },
            driver_address_street: {
                message: "street is Required"
            }
        }
    };  
    if(validateForm($("#addDriverForm"),checkInputs) == true){
    console.log("form submit");
        addNewDriver();
    }
    else{
        console.log("form errors");
    }
    });
```

My full form HTML is

```
   <div class="form-wrapper">

     <form id="addDriverForm" class="post-form" action="modules/add_driver.php" method="post"> 

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_first_name">First Name:</label> 
<input id="driver_first_name" placeholder="John" type="text" name="driver_first_name">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_last_name">Last Name:</label> 
<input id="driver_last_name" placeholder="Smith" type="text" name="driver_last_name">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_address_street">Street</label> 
<input id="driver_address_street" placeholder="123 Main St." type="text" name="driver_address_street">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_address_city">City</label> 
<input id="driver_address_city" placeholder="Chicago" type="text" name="driver_address_city">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_address_state">State</label> 
<input id="driver_address_state" placeholder="IL" type="text" name="driver_address_state">
</div>


<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_address_zip">Zip</label> 
<input id="driver_address_zip" placeholder="60164" type="number" name="driver_address_zip">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_telephone">Zip</label> 
<input id="driver_telephone" placeholder="60164" type="tel" name="driver_telephone">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_email">E-Mail</label> 
<input id="driver_email" placeholder="60164" type="email" name="driver_email">
</div>


<div class="form-row"><label for="driver_payment_type">Settlement Type</label>
<select id="driver_payment_type" name="driver_payment_type">
  <option value="flat">Flat Rate</option>
  <option value="percent">Percent</option>
  <option value="mile">Per Mile</option>
</select></div>


<div class="form-row">
    <label for="driver_license_number">Lisence #</label>
    <input id="driver_license_number" placeholder="ex:D400-7836-2633" type="number" name="driver_license_number">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label for="driver_license_expiration">Lisence Expiration Date</label>
    <input id="driver_license_expiration" type="date" name="driver_license_expiration">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label for="driver_licence_image">Lisence Copy</label>
    <input id="driver_licence_image" type="file" name="driver_licence_image">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label for="driver_medical_certificate_expiration">Medical Certificate Expiration</label>
    <input id="driver_medical_certificate_expiration" type="date" name="driver_medical_certificate_expiration">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label for="driver_medical_certificate_image">Medical CXertificate Copy</label>
    <input id="driver_medical_certificate_image" type="file" name="driver_medical_certificate_image">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label class="driverCheckbox" for="driver_access_mobile_app">Allow Mobile Access</label>
    <input id="driver_access_mobile_app" checked value="1" type="checkbox" name="driver_access_mobile_app">
</div>
<div class="form-row"></div>
<div class="driver-access-copnditional">
<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_username">Username</label> 
<input id="driver_username" placeholder="JohSmi" type="text" name="driver_username">
</div>


<div class="form-row">
<label for="driver_password">Password</label> 
<input id="driver_password" placeholder="***" type="password" name="driver_password">
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="submitNewUnit button green"><i class="material-icons">save</i>Submit</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation logic is a little messed up. This is what's happening:

1. `#driver_first_name` is validated as invalid... `result` is set `false`
2. `#driver_last_name` is validated as valid... `result` is set `true`
3. `#driver_address_street` is validated as valid... `result` is set `true`

After all that the code thinks the form is valid. You're only preventing the form from being submitted if the last field as validated as not-valid.

Change your logic to assume the form is valid from the beginning. Then set it to false if any of the fields are invalid.

I also don't see anything in your code that actually prevents the form submition, so I also added `e.preventDefault()`

```js
function validateForm(form, fields) { //add exit anbimation and reset the container state
  $(".form-input-error").remove();
  var result = true;
  $.each(fields.rules, function(key, value) {
    if (!$("#" + key + "").val()) {
      $("#" + key + "").addClass("form-error");
      $("<div class='form-input-error'>" + value.message + "</div>").insertBefore("#" + key + "");
      result = false;
      //console.log(this.val());
    } else {
      $("#" + key + "").removeClass("form-error");
    }
  });
  return result;
}

$(".app-canvas").on('click', ".submitNewDriver", function(e) { //list all drivers trigger
  var checkInputs = {
    rules: {
      driver_first_name: {
        message: "First Name is Required"
      },
      driver_last_name: {
        message: "Last Name is Required"
      },
      driver_address_street: {
        message: "street is Required"
      }
    }
  };
  if (validateForm($("#addDriverForm"), checkInputs) == true) {
    console.log("form submit");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form errors");
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-canvas form-wrapper">

  <form id="addDriverForm" class="post-form" action="" method="post">

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_first_name">First Name:</label>
      <input id="driver_first_name" placeholder="John" type="text" name="driver_first_name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_last_name">Last Name:</label>
      <input id="driver_last_name" placeholder="Smith" type="text" name="driver_last_name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_address_street">Street</label>
      <input id="driver_address_street" placeholder="123 Main St." type="text" name="driver_address_street">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_address_city">City</label>
      <input id="driver_address_city" placeholder="Chicago" type="text" name="driver_address_city">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_address_state">State</label>
      <input id="driver_address_state" placeholder="IL" type="text" name="driver_address_state">
    </div>


    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_address_zip">Zip</label>
      <input id="driver_address_zip" placeholder="60164" type="number" name="driver_address_zip">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_telephone">Zip</label>
      <input id="driver_telephone" placeholder="60164" type="tel" name="driver_telephone">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_email">E-Mail</label>
      <input id="driver_email" placeholder="60164" type="email" name="driver_email">
    </div>


    <div class="form-row"><label for="driver_payment_type">Settlement Type</label>
      <select id="driver_payment_type" name="driver_payment_type">
      <option value="flat">Flat Rate</option>
      <option value="percent">Percent</option>
      <option value="mile">Per Mile</option>
    </select></div>


    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_license_number">Lisence #</label>
      <input id="driver_license_number" placeholder="ex:D400-7836-2633" type="number" name="driver_license_number">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_license_expiration">Lisence Expiration Date</label>
      <input id="driver_license_expiration" type="date" name="driver_license_expiration">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_licence_image">Lisence Copy</label>
      <input id="driver_licence_image" type="file" name="driver_licence_image">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_medical_certificate_expiration">Medical Certificate Expiration</label>
      <input id="driver_medical_certificate_expiration" type="date" name="driver_medical_certificate_expiration">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="driver_medical_certificate_image">Medical CXertificate Copy</label>
      <input id="driver_medical_certificate_image" type="file" name="driver_medical_certificate_image">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="driverCheckbox" for="driver_access_mobile_app">Allow Mobile Access</label>
      <input id="driver_access_mobile_app" checked value="1" type="checkbox" name="driver_access_mobile_app">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row"></div>
    <div class="driver-access-copnditional">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="driver_username">Username</label>
        <input id="driver_username" placeholder="JohSmi" type="text" name="driver_username">
      </div>


      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="driver_password">Password</label>
        <input id="driver_password" placeholder="***" type="password" name="driver_password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="submitNewDriver button green" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed my original function by adding double quotes around "true", but in hindsight I can see why reversing the logic would make sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just to note, the form trigger is not a submit <button>, that's why I didn't need to prevent default behavior.  It triggers the  addNewDriver();  function which handles a few other things including an ajax POST or GET parameters.

Comment: Gotcha... I almost forgot I had made that change :D